# Sequence in $\mathbb R^2$ converges if and only if it is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

How to prove that a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ converges if and only if it is Cauchy?

I've proven that the triangle inequality holds for the euclidean norm of vectors.

Comment: Welcome! See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). (I reformatted your question). Also, do you know that the convergence of a sequence in $\mathbb R^2$ can be tested one coordinate at a time? Finally, have you searched the site or looked at the *Related* questions on the right?

Answer (score 1):

Like 900 sit-ups a day pointed out a sequence $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ converges if and only if the sequences $(\pi_i(x_k))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge for all $i$ with $1\le i\le n$ where $\pi_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is the projection to the $i$th coordinate. So you have to show that the sequences $(\pi_i(x_k))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ are Cauchy and then use the result for $\mathbb{R}$ that a sequence converges if and only if it is Cauchy.